# Using different prototypes depending on type in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im playing around with Ember.js atm and Im not really used to the concept so far. What I want to do now is to build a little cms and I need something like a Class or Object depending on the type of content. E.g. I load up an element of the type text, this type has some content. Another Element is of the type Section, this has the attributes size, color and whatever. What I need now is to let the route decide, what kind of content it has loaded, and depending on that build omething new with the special properties. Let's say

```
Ember Route loads content, looks up type
  if type == text
    make a new text-oject/class with properties name, heading, content

  if type==section
    make a new section-object/class with properties color, size etc.
```

How do I achieve this in Ember, so that I have some kind of prototype for each content-type, and load the used properties from different db-relations?

**Edit:**
Ok, I try to explain it a little bit better. I have a database with three different relations 'elements', 'content' and 'attributes'. Right now I have a route that gets the id of an element. With this id I can get the element itself, that has the field 'type'. What I want to do (if that is possible) is this:

```
model(params) {
  element=this.store.queryRecord('element', {id: params.id});
  if (element.type == section) {
    return new sectionElement(params.id)
  }
}

SectionElement {
  construct(id) {
    element: this.store.queryRecord('element', id),
    size: this.store.query('attribute', foreignKey=id),
  }
  update() {
    update element and size
  }
}

TextElement {
  construct(id) {
    element: this.store.queryRecord('element', id),
    text: this.store.query('content', foreignKey=id),
  }
  update() {
    update element and text
  }
}

actions: {
  newElement(type) {
    if (type==section) {
      return new SectionElement 
    }
  }
}
```

I Know I cant work with Promises like that in the model, but maybe it gets a little bit more understandable what I want to do. As I tried to explain before, I need some kind of prototype, that knows what values are important and where to store them. I am still not sure if Ember can do that or if I need to work another way.

Comment: What do you mean by `build something new with the special properties` ? What is the `something`? A template? A helper? An object or a function? Not all of these should be built in the same part of an Ember app. Also, how are you loading your model? Overall be a little more specific with what you **exactly** you need.

Comment: That `something` depends on what the type of content is. I need to render different components within my template (I'd do that with a helper in my template). What I need right now is an, lets call it object, that nows, where to find the important things and has some methods to update or delete. Im not really bound to a special way of loading the model, I'd love to load the model of the content (this.store.queryRecord) and let my object decide what to load next. I could also load it with RSVP.hash, to load all the data right there, but sometimes i dont get values from specific relations.

Comment: I was also thinkiing about using `beforeModel` and inside that decide, which type of content I got and setting up different lists for the rsvp.hash, use the same component for everything and put a lot of conditionals in it

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If you show more code (or at least pseudocode) maybe I can help you but right now I cannot really follow what you said here. Statements such as `What I need right now is an, lets call it object, that nows, where to find the important things and has some methods to update or delete.` are vague and can mean many things. Try to be more specific and I will definitely try to help. For example, what is the format of your `model` or `content` as you call it? Does it have a `type` field that you can check and determine which object to create (a Class or a Section)?